# How to compare oracle date and lotusscript date?

Tags: oracle, date, lotusscript

In the oracle table is a column containing the last modified date of current row. How do I format a date in Lotusscript so that it is comparable to the oracle date type? I've tried CStr and TO_CHAR but that is only comparing the characters, not actual dates. If possible I want to create a date in lotusscript that requires no formatting but can be compared to the oracle date. Something like LAST_MODIFIED > lastdate (this oracle date is greater than the lotussciript date). I've no control of the oracle table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an Oracle date using the to_date function.

to_date(,'format')

Format your date as a string for example: 06-05-2012 and this will return an Oracle date:

In plsql that would look like:

```
my_string := '06-08-2012';
my_date := to_date(my_string,'DD-MM-YYYY');
```

But of course you can do this in SQL directly.

```
where LAST_MODIFIED > to_date(<your_date_string_to_compare>,<your_date_format>)
```